# Local Area Connection icon is always bright in Windows XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp, networking

I'm using Windows XP, the Local Area Connection icon is always bright in the task bar, i know this indicates there are live connection(you are sending or receiving data from/to network), however, i didn't use the network at all, how can i see which process is consuming the connection? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) from Sysinternals Suite which is able to list active network connections.